# FPDF: Report data not generates for calendar selected date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, fpdf

Jquery date picker selected date is not filtering data for fpdf report. (I have added the related codes below.)

### datepicker js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datepicker12").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
   $("#datepicker12").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
});
```

### form HTML

```
<form id="salesReportForm" name="salesReportForm" method="post" action="../reports/dailyreports.php" >
```

### datepicker HTML

```
<input id="datepicker12"  name="datepicker12" tabindex="6" class="txtbx" />
```

### Button submit

```
<a target="popup" onclick="window.open('../reports/monthlyreports.php','popup','width=1200,height=900'); return false;">
                  <input type="button" name="btnMonthlyReports" id="btnMonthlyReports" value="GENERATE" />
                </a>
```

### report.php (FPDF)

```
if(isset($_POST['datepicker12'])){ $date = $_POST['datepicker12'];}

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT S.sales_id, I.item_name, ST.stock_code, S.qty, S.unit_price, S.discount, S.amount, S.date
                 FROM sales S 
                 INNER JOIN items I ON S.item_id=I.item_id 
                 INNER JOIN stock ST ON S.stock_id=ST.stock_id WHERE S.date BETWEEN $date.'00:00:00' AND $date.'23:59:59'"); 

$pdf->Cell(25,6,$date,'B',0,'L',0);
```

When I debug the code, below error appears.

"Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''00:00:00' AND .'23:59:59'' at line 4 "

Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry I couldn't find any. There is only one parenthesis pair.

Comment: Like this ($connection,"SELECT ......AND $date.'23:59:59'");

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, can you please edit my code as you suggest, since I have no clue what you are mentioning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, and now it works perfectly. I removed `<a>` from wrapping the submit button, and it worked.

Edited code is as below:

```
<form id="dailysalesReportForm" name="dailysalesReportForm" method="post" action="../reports/dailyreports.php" ><tr>
                <td width="147" height="34"><div align="left">DAILY</div></td>
                  <td width="116"><label>
                    <div align="center">
                      <input id="datepicker12"  name="datepicker12" tabindex="6" class="txtbx" />
                    </div>
                    </label>
                    <div align="center"></div></td>
                  <td width="104"><div align="center"></div></td>
                  <td width="81"><label>
                    <div align="center"> 
                      <input type="submit" name="btnDailyReports" id="btnDailyReports" value="GENERATE"/>
                    </div>
                    </label></td>
              </tr></form>
```